# Remove the tuple and create a new sorted list

Tags: python, pyspark, tuples, apache-spark-sql, pyhdfs-client

I have a **RDD** which I created using **PySpark** and sizes around **600 GB** after joining by key value which looks exactly like this.

```
[('43.72_-70.08', (('0744632', -70.08, 43.72, '2.4'), '18090865')),
 ('43.72_-70.08', (('0744632', -70.08, 43.72, '2.4'), '18090865')),
 ('43.25_-67.58', (('0753877', -67.58, 43.25, '7.2'), '18050868')),
 ('43.01_-75.24', (('0750567', -75.24, 43.01, '7.2'), '18042872'))]
```

**I want** something like this and sorted by the first element:

```
['0744632', '18090865', '2.4',
'0744632', '18090865', '2.4',
'0750567', '18042872', '7.2',
'0753877', '18050868', '7.2']
```

Is there a way I can get data from tuples out and get the output in required format.

Note: This is a 600 GB RDD, with more than a million different values in first column and approx. 15 billion rows, I would really appreciate an optimized way if possible.

Comment: That's not a valid list.  Error, tuples are not callable, probably missing a comma.

Comment: Try this

`new_data = [ [y[1][0][0],y[1][1],y[1][0][3]]  for y in tuple_list]`
`sorted_data = sorted(new_data)`

Comment: Do you really want a flattened list, vs a list of tuples?

Comment: @AChampion I want an RDD in this format.

Comment: @HungryMind Your code works but is applicable for lists, mine is RDD, I should have been more clear on that. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in your spark cluster, e.g.:

```
In []:
(rdd.map(lambda x: (x[1][0][0], x[1][1], x[1][0][2]))
 .sortBy(lambda x: x[0])
 .flatMap(lambda x: x)
 .collect())

Out[]:
['0744632', '18090865', 43.72, '0744632', '18090865', 43.72, '0750567', 
 '18042872', 43.01, '0753877', '18050868', 43.25]
```

Alternatively

```
In []:
import operator as op

(rdd.map(lambda x: (x[1][0][0], x[1][1], x[1][0][2]))
 .sortBy(lambda x: x[0])
 .reduce(op.add))

Out[]:
('0744632', '18090865', 43.72, '0744632', '18090865', 43.72, '0750567', 
 '18042872', 43.01, '0753877', '18050868', 43.25)
```

This seems like a rather unwieldy structure, if you meant a list of tuples then simply eliminate the `flatMap()`:

```
In []:
(rdd.map(lambda x: (x[1][0][0], x[1][1], x[1][0][2]))
 .sortBy(lambda x: x[0])
 .collect())

Out[]:
[('0744632', '18090865', 43.72),
 ('0744632', '18090865', 43.72),
 ('0750567', '18042872', 43.01),
 ('0753877', '18050868', 43.25)]
```

Comment: I got this error ... Is it because I am running out of memory?
**Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 42 tasks (1107.9 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)**

Comment: Change the size of your max result size `sc.getConf().set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "2g")`

Comment: This is not helping, I still get the same error. Can you please help me with this error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple one line solution

```
sorted([(x[1][0][0], x[1][1], x[1][0][3]) for x in your_list])
```

I think it's slightly faster than a lambda solution based on this post
[What is the difference between these two solutions - lambda or loop - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076692/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-solutions-lambda-or-loop-python)

Comment: *I have an RDD can't use this one, but this do work for lists*

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other Spark answer:

```
rdd=rdd.map(lambda (a,(b,c)): [b[0], c, b[3]])\
       .sortBy(lambda row: row[0])
```

You can also use reduce instead of flatMap:

```
rdd.reduce(lambda x,y: x+y)
```