# removing duplicate objects inside of array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this question might look similar:

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014324/remove-duplicated-object-in-array)

but it isn't.

I have an array like this.

*console.log output*

```
serviceListData: Array(4) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
​​
0: Object { Id: 1939808, count: 1 }
​​
1: Object { Id: 1939808, count: 2 }
​​
2: Object { Id: 1940022, count: 1 }
​​
3: Object { Id: 1940022, count: 2 }
```

I want to remove objects with duplicate Id but also, I want to keep the latest value.
there's no guarantee that the latest value will always be bigger like the example above.

it could be 2,1 2,1 in `count` property.

how can I do this?
keeping the latest count and removing duplicate Ids?

Comment: Iterate through the array and assign a key/value to an object with the id as the key.  Then you can take the `Object.values` of them to get an array back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming by "latest value" you mean highest index in the array, you can `reduce` the array and continue setting / resetting the value at the key, then take the values from the resulting object.

Something like:

```
Object.values(
  serviceListData
    .reduce((acc, next) => ({...acc, [next.Id]: next }), {})
)
```