# Count occurrences in an array in O(n log n) time

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Given an unsorted array, `A[]`, containing `n` integers, how would one create an algorithm to return the element that occurred most often?

I figure you'd need a way to count the number of times an element occurs. I can only figure out an *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* implementation. I know I need to use a sorting algorithm first, but if I were to use merge sort, that's already the total runtime of *O(n logn))*. I've only sorted the data and I can't look at the elements without further increasing the runtime.

Comment: If sorting the array is a possibility, merge sort will do the trick making it n logn, after that a simple n iteration will do the trick

Comment: Not an answer, but a clue. O(n log n) + O(n) is still O(n log n). Big-O notation only cares about the dominant term.

Comment: @DavidC I thought you would multiply them--not add them! If had known that, I wouldn't have asked this question. Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sort the array, then, all repeating elements are next to each other. 

Simply iterate the array, while holding a `maxSeen` and `currSeen` counters, if current element equals last element, increase `currSeen`, otherwise - reset `currSeen`, and replace `maxSeen` if the `currSeen` is bigger than it.

Sorting is O(nlogn), and iterating once is O(n), so total of `O(nlogn + n) = O(nlogn)`

It's homework, so following this guidelines to create a code should be your task. Good Luck!

---

As a side note, since this is at least as hard as [Element Distinctness Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem), and [it cannot be done better than O(nlogn)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7055544/572670) using comparisons based algorithms.

---

Side note two, it can be done in `O(n)` time + space using hash-tables.

Create a histogram of the data, which is a hash-map, inwhich a key is an element, and the value is number of occurances. Then, the problem decays to finding maximal value in this hash table.

Building the table is `O(n)` average case, and finding maximum is `O(n)`.

This however uses `O(n)` extra memory, and might deteriorate to `O(n^2)` time under worst case behavior.

Comment: I hadn't heard of the Element Distinctness Problem. Thanks for including that link!

Comment: @templatetypedef Look at the second link as well, it points to the articles that proves lower bound using algebraic trees model. (of course it can be done in O(n) average case  and space, using hashes, but not using comparisons)

Answer (score 3):

You surmise correctly that it's a good idea to start by sorting the array. This costs *O(n log n)*, as you point out. Then you can scan the array and compute the frequency of each value one by one, remembering the most frequent value as you go along. This costs *O(n)*. The total cost is *O(n log n + n)*, which is in *O(n log n)*.

To see why, consider *O(2n log n)*. This is surely in *O(n log n)* because *2n log n* is within a constant factor of *n log n*. And *n log n + n* is bounded above by *2n log n*, so it is also in *O(n log n)*.

Comment: I didn't realize that that you would add the two runtimes, not multiply them. That's me being stupid. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

just take a dictionary store every number in it as key, and value as its count initially 1 if number repeated again increase that count otherwise input it in dict.

traverse through each key value in dictionary whose value is greater its key will be largest among all

solved in n+n =2n ~> n

Comment: Please note that this is a 4 year old question with already accepted answer. and hashmap/dictionary suggestion is already covered in accepted answer.