# Array - Dupe Scanner and runtime of algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime

I got two tasks to do:

1.) Create an algorithm so it detects if there are duplicates (= same numbers) in an array (the better its runtime is, the more points I get).

2.) Analyze the runtime of your algorithm.

Here is my code for the first task (I had to sort the array so the algorithm works faster / works at all. For this I used `import` instead of coding it myself.):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Dupescanner
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 8, 8};
        Arrays.sort(A);
        System.out.println("Following numbers are duplicates:");
        for (int n = 1; n < A.length; n++)
        {
            if (A[n] == A[n - 1])
            {
                System.out.println(A[n]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Following numbers are duplicates:
1
2
8
```

Is that algorithm fine? I couldn't think of anything that is faster than this one. Or maybe I mis understood the task and it's enough if you just say:
true - there is / are duplicates. false - not...

For the runtime analysis, I wasn't sure but I gave it a try as well:

```
int[] A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 8, 8};
```

costs 1

the for loop costs n and the if costs n too. 
Result would be n^2 + 1. Also I'm not sure if the array sort counts, I excluded it.

Comment: If you have java 8 you can use parallel streams

Comment: @mariusz2108 That has nothing to do with this question though.

Comment: @tenepolis The array sort does count. You can't exclude it just because you didn't write the code for it.

Comment: Why did you exclude the array sort? It should be included if it's used in duplicate detection. Also, you state the result would be `n^2 + 1`. This is incorrect as you iterate across all elements only once.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is `O(nlogn)`, the bottleneck in here is the sorting.

Your loop runs in linear time.

This is in fact the [element distinctness problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem).

It can be solved more efficiently (in terms of asymptotic complexity) only if you allow hashing and extra space, by populating a hash table ([`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)), and inserting all elements into it while iterating, and if you find a dupe while iterating - print it.

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 8, 8};
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
System.out.println("Following numbers are duplicates:");
for (int e : array) { 
  if (!set.add(e)) System.out.println("" + e);
}
```

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7055508/572670) discusses lower bounds for the problem.