# How can I improve the time complexity of the following program " Remove duplicates from an array"?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I am new to Data Structures and Algorithms. I was working on a problem set which is basically to remove duplicates from an array and return the array without the duplicates. My goal was to design an efficient algorithm which can solve this problem. I used the approach of writing a Naive code and then finding various ways to improve the time complexity of the code. Currently, the code I wrote has a time complexity of O(n^2). So, I was wondering if someone can kindly point out the possible improvements on my code so that I can bring down the time complexity from O(n^2) to O(nlogn) or O(n) if possible. Please I am trying to approach this problem without sorting the array.
Thanks.

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       int [] a= {1,7,7,7,9,9,10,10,10,11,11,1};
        removeduplicates(a);




    }

    public static void removeduplicates(int[]a)
    {
        int flag=0;
        int b =0;
        int k=0;
        int [] temp = new int[a.length];
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            int key = a[i];
            for(int j=i+1;j<a.length;j++)
            {
                if(key==a[j])
                {
                    flag++;

                }
            }

            if(flag==0)
            {
                temp[k] = key;
                k++;

            }

            else
            {
                for( int m=0;m<temp.length;m++)
                {
                    if(key==temp[m])
                    {
                        b++;
                    }
                }

                if(b==0)
                {
                    temp[k] = key;
                    k++;
                }
            }

            b = 0;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
            System.out.print(temp[i] +"\t");

    }


}
```

// The following code is a improvement on the above code with a time complexity of O(n). Thanks @Bohemian for the suggestions:-

```
import java.util.HashSet;


public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          HashSet<Integer> hs = new HashSet<Integer>();
           int [] a= {1,7,7,7,9,9,10,10,10,11,11,1};

           for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
           {
              hs.add(a[i]);
           }

           Integer [] rtrn = new Integer[hs.size()];
           rtrn = hs.toArray(rtrn);

           for(int i=0;i<rtrn.length;i++)
               System.out.print(rtrn[i] +"\t");

    }

}
```

Comment: If your code is working, you should ask on [codereview.se].

Comment: Java8 way: `a = IntStream.of(a).distinct().toArray();`

Comment: @shashwatZing: the solution is O(n) because the values lie in a limited range (0..1000). That is generally not a viable solution.

Comment: Analysis and lower bounds of this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7055508/572670

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An O(n) solution in pseudo code is:

- create a HashSet
- for each value, discard it if the set already contains it

Because all operations on a HashSet are O(1), and you do n of these, the overall complexity is O(n).

You may find this line useful:

```
if (!set.add(i)) continue;
```

The `add()` method of a set returns `true` if the set was modified by the operation (ie if it didn't already contain the value).

Comment: Depending on the range of `int` values, a `BitSet` could be used. +1

Comment: @Bohemian:- Thanks. I actually followed your suggestion and wrote a nice neat code. I have updated the new code along with the old code. Thank you again.

Comment: @Melissa you've missed my point entirely. First, delete the `flag` variable. It isn't needed or even used. Secondly, the entire body of the loop can be replaced with simply: `hs.add(a[i]);` - add() won't allow duplicates

Comment: @Bohemian:- Thanks again. I will make the necessary corrections.