# best algorithm which detects if an array of numbers has identical numbers

Tags: algorithm

The algorithm only need to detect if there are at least 2 number which are the same.

Is the one in my picture the best way to do it or is there a more effective way.

This is a task in a book and I don't no if i did it right.

Algorithm

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  Please take a look at item 3 of [What topics can I ask about?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I assume the book is asking you to code that algorithm, which is two nested loops. Not the most efficient but straightforwards and workable.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055508/find-duplicates-in-an-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find duplicates in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055508/find-duplicates-in-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array is sorted:

```
for(int i=0; i<a.length-1; i++)
  if(a[i]==a[i+1])
    return true;
return false;
```

if the array is not sorted, use a cache:

```
boolean[] cache=new boolean[N];
Arrays.fill(cache,false); //set all values to false

for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
  if(cache[a[i]])
    return true;
  else
    cache[a[i]]=true; //mark element a[i] as seen
return false;
```

In the above, N is the maximum value that occurs in array a. If N is unknown or very large, or your array contains negative values, use a map instead of an array as cache.

Both solutions run in O(n) time. The second solution just needs an external cache to remember which elements we've seen before.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do:

```
Loop on I
      Loop on j
             If value of a[I] = value of a[j]
                   Break;  /*at least one double found*/
```

No?

Wrong.. Forget about it..