# In less-than-linear time, find the duplicate in a sorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, language-agnostic, data-structures

Today, an interviewer asked me this question. My immediate response was that we could simply do a linear search, comparing the current element with the previous element in the array. He then asked me how the problem could be solved in less-than-linear time.

**Assumptions**

- The array is **sorted**
- There is only **one** duplicate
- The array is **only** populated with numbers `[0, n]`, where `n` is the length of the array.

**Example array**: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,9]

I attempted to come up with a divide-and-conquer algorithm to solve this, but I'm not confident that it was the right answer.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: your example includes only numbers `[0,n-2]` (there are no `10`, `11`) Is it just an example or a general rule?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Can be done in O(log N) with a modified binary search:

Start in the middle of the array: If array[idx] < idx the duplicate is to the left, otherwise to the right. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: It should be `array[idx]-array[0]` for generic version.

Answer (score 7):

If no number is missing from the array, as in the example, it's doable in O(log n) with a binary search. If `a[i] < i`, the duplicate is before `i`, otherwise it's after `i`.

If there is one number absent and one duplicate, we still know that if `a[i] < i` the duplicate must be before `i` and if `a[i] > i`, the absent number must be before `i` and the duplicate after. However, if `a[i] == i`, we don't know if missing number and duplicate are both before `i` or both after `i`. I don't see a way for a sublinear algorithm in that case.

Comment: I'm very late, but if you allow missing numbers, it's indeed impossible (assuming you can't read an arbitrarily large number of cells in O(1)). Suppose we consider entries of size n+1 (n>=2) and we limit ourselves to this subset of entries : {[0,0,2,…,n], [0,1,1,3,…,n], ..., [0,1,…,k,k,k+2,…,n], ..., [0,1,…,n-1,n-1]}. Let's assume you already know the contents of any of up to (n-2) cells and that they were pairwise distinct, there's still at least 2 possibilities and you can't discriminate any. Therefore you need to read at least (n-1) cells to decide which number is the duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

> *I attempted to come up with a divide-and-conquer algorithm to solve this, but I'm not confident that it was the right answer.*

Sure, you could do a binary search.

If `arr[i/2] >= i/2` then the duplicate is located in the upper half of the array, otherwise it is located in the lower half.

```
while (lower != upper)
    mid = (lower + upper) / 2
    if (arr[mid] >= mid)
        lower = mid
    else
        upper = mid-1
```

Since the array between `lower` and `upper` is halved in each iteration, the algorithm runs in O(log n).

[ideone.com demo in Java](http://ideone.com/oOCE0)

Answer (score 1):

Difference between sum of given array elements and sum of 0 to n-1 natural numbers gives you the duplicated element.
Sum of 0 to n-1 elements is (N * N-1)/2
example array is [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,9]
sum of 0 to 9 natural numbers is : 45
sum of given array elements : 53
53-45 = 8 Which is the duplicated element

Comment: adding up all elements is O(n) - and therefore over budget

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int find_only_repeating_element(int arr[] , int n){
int low = 0;
int high = n-1;
while(low <= high){
    int mid = low + (high - low)/2;
    if(arr[mid] == arr[mid + 1] || arr[mid] == arr[mid - 1]){
        return arr[mid];
    }
    if(arr[mid] < mid + 1){
        high = mid - 2;
    }else{
        low = mid + 1;
    }
   }
   return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
int n , *arr;
cin >> n;
arr = new int[n];
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
    cin >> arr[i];
}
    cout << find_only_repeating_element(arr , n) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider adding some explanation to your code when  answering a question.

Answer (score 0):

How about that?   (recursion style)

```
public static int DuplicateBinaryFind(int[] arr, int left, int right)
{
   int dup =0;

   if(left==right)
   {
      dup = left;
   }
   else
   {
        int middle = (left+right)\2;
        if(arr[middle]<middle)
        {
          dup = DuplicateBinaryFind(arr,left, middle-1);

        }
        else
        {
           dup = DuplicateBinaryFind(arr, middle+1, right);
        }
   }

   return dup;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The example array is a little bit different from your question. Since n is the length of array and there are one and only duplicate in array, the value of each element in array should be in [0,n-1].

If that is true, then this question is the same one with [How to find a duplicate element in an array of shuffled consecutive integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605766/how-to-find-a-duplicate-element-in-an-array-of-shuffled-consecutive-integers)

The following code should find the duplicate in O(n) time and O(1) space.

```
public static int findOnlyDuplicateFromArray(int[] a, boolean startWithZero){
    int xor = 0;
    int offset = 1;
    for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++){
        if(startWithZero)
            xor = xor ^ (a[i] + offset) ^ i;
        else
            xor = xor ^ a[i] ^ i;
        }
        if(startWithZero)
            xor = xor - offset;
    return xor;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not a less linear time. Should use binary search to achieve the goal.