# Thinking Process of an algorithm of find the missing element in a given permutation from Codility

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

I found this perfect answer for the [Codility's PermMissingElem Questio](https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/1)n.

```
function solution($A) {
    $N   = count($A);
    $sum = ($N + 2) * ($N + 1) / 2;
    for($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++){
        $sum -= $A[$i];
    }
    return intval($sum);
}
```

However I found its puzzled for me regarding the $sum's function. What kind of function is this? It's amazingly correctly, yet, how come someone could make up such function? **Is there anyone can somehow reverse engineer the thinking process?
I really want to know the process how it came about.**

Thank You !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959397/duplicate-element-in-array/27959534#27959534 apart from this question which is similar I am sure this is a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of integers from 1 to N can be calculated by this formula:

```
N(N+1)/2
```

Basically, you take the first number and the last number and add them together, and then the second number and the second to last number..etc.

For example:

The sum of 1 to 100:

```
(1+100) + (2+99) + (3+98) + (4+97) ...
= (100/2)(101)
= 50 x 101
```

Here's a good explanation:

http://www.wikihow.com/Sum-the-Integers-from-1-to-N

Comment: I know its amateur... But its just wow, still, so amazing!.... Learned it couple years back, totally forgot about it lol Thanks man :)