# The best way to find the single number in pairs or triples

Tags: algorithm

As this is one question in a series of questions. I am modifying this to make it not duplicate from other ones. Thanks for all the help.

**Pairs**: I have an array of integers. In the array, every element appears twice except for one. I want to find that single number.

Example: `[2, 4, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3]`, single number is `3`.

My thought is to use a `HashMap`, which takes `O(n)` time and `O(n)` space. Are there any better solutions? Thanks.

**Triples**: every element appears three times except for one. Find that single one.

Example: `[1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3]`, single number is `3`.

Comment: Is the array somehow orderd, such that the elements that are twice appear always in pairs like in your example. or is an array like [1,2,3,1,2] allowed, to?

Comment: @AlexWien No, it is in random order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accenture interview question - find the only unpaired element in the array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644179/accenture-interview-question-find-the-only-unpaired-element-in-the-array)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29333689/768110 http://stackoverflow.com/q/35185/768110

Comment: @RiaD Hi, thanks for pointing that out. I have modified the question. Please check again.

Comment: @Noob making existing answer irrelevant

Comment: @RiaD It is still to find the single number. I will add some more explanations. Maybe Panda has a solution for the new problem as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think about solving it in the "bit" way, which takes `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space:

```
public class Solution {
    public int singleNumber(int[] A) {
        if (A.length==0) return 0;
        if (A.length==1) return A[0];

        int result = A[0];

        for (int i=1; i<A.length; i++) {
            result = result ^ A[i];
        }

        return result;         
    }
}
```

Well, yes, I also have the solution for finding the single one in triples.

```
public class Solution {
    public int singleNumber(int[] A) {
        int result = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            int curr = 0;
            for (int num : A) {
                curr += (num >> i) & 1;
            }
            result += (curr % 3) << i;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

This can be more difficult for you to understand. Please read some materials about bit manipulation and then figure out how this solution works.

Comment: Interesting, Is that from "Hackers Delight"

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. What is "^"?

Comment: @AlexWien Just solved this problem before. I was even shocked when I saw this bit manipulation solution.

Comment: @Noob, about ^ (xor) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991380/what-does-the-operator-do-in-java

Comment: @Learner Thanks. I will google and get to know more about this.

Comment: @IgorTyulkanov Thank you.

Comment: @Noob if you solved it with the hashmap, that would be the normal solution. The trick with xor, one has to know. The book "Hackers Delight " shows such tricks with bit manipulation,.

Comment: Hi, do you have a solution for the new edited question by any chance? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AlexWien I did not read "Hackers Delight". I got the solutions from other websites when I was preparing for some interviews.

Comment: @Panda Thank you so much!

Comment: Intersting, which company needs such bit tricks, maybe Nvidia, but who else?

Comment: @AlexWien I was preparing for Google onsite interviews. Just in case, it was better to know about bit manipulations.